# RaspberryPI cannot change permission of mounted hdd due to rpi-first-boot-wizard user

Tags: permissions, mount, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I mounted an external hdd into `/mnt/edisk` on my raspberry pi. If I check ownership, strangely I see this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 19 rpi-first-boot-wizard rpi-first-boot-wizard 128K May 10 17:44 edisk
```

I can write to this disk with `sudo` But I want to change permission to my user `pi`.

Tried to do this with `chown -R pi /mnt/edisk` but this is throwing `Operation not permitted` error.

What is rpi-first-boot-wizard? How can I change permissions?

#### update

This is an exFat formatted disk

#### update 2

This is the command I am using to mount:

```
sudo mount -t exfat -o uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=007 /dev/sda1 /mnt/edisk/
```

`mount | grep edisk` is showing:

```
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/edisk type exfat (rw,relatime,uid=1001,gid=1001,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,iocharset=utf8,errors=remount-ro)
```

Comment: Apparently the same question: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/137467/139666

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the complete `mount` command you used to mount the HDD. What OS version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

exFat looks like do not have separate bite for owner, so you need to mount it with option:

```
cd
sudo umount /mnt/edisk
sudo mount -o uid=pi,gid=$(id -gn pi) /dev/device /mnt/edisk
```

So it will mount the disk as a specific user.

to make it available after reboot and mount now:

```
sudo -s
echo "/dev/DEVICE /mnt/edisk exfat defaults,uid=pi,gid=$(id -gn pi) 0 
0 " >> /etc/fstab
systemctl daemon-reload
mount -av
exit
```

Comment: `/mnt/edisk/etc/passwd` does not exist. This is an extarnal hdd used as storage

Comment: "copy files with sudo to mounted disk." - what files?

Comment: oh, sorry, missread it. Then just run: `sudo chown -Rc /mnt/edisk`

Comment: still does not work with sudo.. look at updated question

Comment: can you show mount command you used? and `mount | grep edisk`

Comment: Tried this but still user is root

Comment: updated the question to show how I am mounting